# How to choose a long tail keyword from such a long list?

Tags: seo, keywords, content

I have created this list of different keywords related to Florida villas and villas near Disney.

How could I make this a lot smaller and manageable?

Would I pick one that sounds well and then just write natural copy and then these will just naturally appear within the article?

I am only writing about 600 words per community, so there is not that much I can write.

- villa florida
- villa for rent orlando area,
- villa homes for rent in orlando florida
- villa in kissimmee florida orlando
- villa in orlando near disney world
- villa rental orlando disney
- villa resorts near disney world
- villa to rent in orlando kissimmee area
- villas around disney world
- villas close to disney
- villas close to disney world
- villas close to disney world orlando
- villas close to universal studios
- villas close to universal studios orlando
- villas for rent in clearwater florida
- villas for rent in davenport orlando
- villas for rent in orlando disney area
- villas for rent in orlando florida
- villas for rent in orlando florida near disney
- villas for rent in orlando kissimmee
- villas for rent near disney
- villas for rent near disney world
- villas for rent near universal studios orlando
- villas in celebration florida
- villas in clearwater beach florida

The list goes on.

Comment: Search is not about keywords. It is about whole language. Do not think of keywords, but rather, as Stephen says in his answer, topics. Search engines do not match search terms directly. Not even close. Cheers!!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to (or even want to) use any of those phrases exactly.   Rather you want to make sure that your article addresses a number of the concepts for which people are searching.   The best way to use a list of long-tail keywords is to find out what people are interested in and make sure you address those interests.

Given your example you might write a blurb about a specific Villa:

> #### Bob's Best Villa
>
> Bob's Best Villa is a charming 2 bedroom retreat located in Kissimmee, FL.  It has [all these amenities]...
>
> Many visitors rent this villa to visit Disney World which is only a few minutes away.  Other near by attractions include:
>
> - Orlando - [X minutes or hours] away
> - Universal Studios - [X minutes or hours] away
> - ...

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to find the best keywords, Just run the ads(Adword) for all these keywords. Find out, which gives better ROI/Conv, then select those keywords.

Comment: If they are long tail, then none of them are going to get enough clicks in ads such that you can make good decisions on that.

Comment: use phrase match in such a way that, all the long tail kwds are covered.